# Mix It Up Jquery Gallery Not Pushing Content Below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the jQuery Gallery Plugin called [Mix It Up](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) and it is failing to push content, such as my footer down below it.

The way in which this gallery is configured is I have a number of div elements set out with backgrounds applied to them to form the gallery. When you initially load the page everything is fine (if loading from a desktop device). However, as you reduce the page width I have changed the layout of the gallery, for example at full width there are four elements per row, at lower breakpoints there are two and so on. Because of this, at lower breakpoints the height of the gallery changes to accommodate for having less items per row. This means that my footer is no longer being pushed down below the gallery.

Here is the HTML for my gallery:

```
    <section id="portfolio">
  <div class="portfolio-title h1">
    <h2>My <span>Work</span></h2>
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-filters">
    <div class="filter" data-filter="all"><img src="asset/Portfolio/loupe.png" alt="View All"/><p>ALL</p></div>
    <div class="filter" data-filter=".category-1"><img src="asset/Portfolio/web.png" alt="Website Design"/><p>WEB</p></div>
    <div class="filter" data-filter=".category-2"><img src="asset/Portfolio/graphic design.png" alt="Graphic Design"/><p>GRAPHIC</p></div>
    <div class="filter" data-filter=".category-3"><img src="asset/Portfolio/picture.png" alt="Content Creation"/><p>CONTENT</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-container">
    <div class="p1 p-content category-1 mix" data-myorder="1"><div></div></div>
    <div class="p2 p-content category-1 mix" data-myorder="3"><div></div></div>
    <div class="p3 p-content category-1 mix" data-myorder="2"><div></div></div>
    <div class="p4 p-content category-1 mix" data-myorder="5"><div></div></div>
    <div class="p5 p-content category-1 mix" data-myorder="4"><div></div></div>
    <div class="p6 p-content category-2 mix" data-myorder="6"><div></div></div>
    <div class="p7 p-content category-3 mix" data-myorder="8"><div></div></div>
    <div class="p9 p-content category-3 mix" data-myorder="7"><div></div></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and here is the CSS for my gallery:

```
/*Portfolio Section */
#portfolio{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.portfolio-title{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.portfolio-title h2{
  color: black;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.portfolio-title hr{
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.portfolio-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.portfolio-container div{
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #363636;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.filter{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 360px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
.filter p{
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.filter img{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.gallery-filters{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.portfolio-container .mix{
  display: none;
}
.p-content div{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.p-content div:hover{
  opacity: 0.7;
}
/*Gallery Images */
.p-content{
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.p1{
  background-image: url('asset/Portfolio/web/thewebcreator.png')
}
.p2{
  background-image: url('asset/Portfolio/web/lussoegusto.png')
}
.p3{
  background-image: url('asset/Portfolio/web/akrams.png')
}
.p4{
  background-image: url('asset/Portfolio/web/adaptive-flair.png')
}
.p5{
  background-image: url('asset/Portfolio/web/codeacation.png');
}
```

I The reason i've included so much code above is to give proper context. In addition. If you visit the site [HERE](http://alexwiley.co.uk/new_site/index.html) then you can use developer tools to inspect further. I am sure the solution is simple.

To add further complication however, the height of the gallery section can also dynamically change as images are filtered out, meaning that I essentially need a way of automatically setting the height of the gallery.

I have spent 2 hours trying to figure this out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fixed 500px height on the container:

```
.portfolio-container {
    ...
    height: 500px;
    ...
}
```

And you set a percentage based height for the child elements (your grid items):

```
.portfolio-container div {
    ...
    height: 50%;
    ...
}
```

If you *remove* the fixed height from `.portfolio-container` and *add* a fixed height to `.portfolio-container div` of `250px`, the Mix It Up plugin will automatically resize the container to accommodate the number of elements currently displayed.

Comment: This actually was an idea I had! However then how do you accommodate for when the user say filters the gallery so that it only has two results? When the user filters down the results the height of the gallery will dynamically change surly? Do correct me if I am wrong here :)

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice the filtering functionality. See updated answer.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for that, I think it just came from a lack of understanding as to how the plugin fully worked. You're a star!

Comment: Just a suggestion: When you hover over an item in your "skills" section don't adjust the `img` width/height. If you use `.skill:hover img { transform: scale(1.2); }` it will prevent the container form resizing and moving the other content.